# ¿Como traspasar información contenida en un archivo hacia una LLS

Tags: c++

tengo una duda con respecto a la sintaxis de como definir un nodo para una lls, en este caso no se como declarar el nodo con un template con el nombre de la clase para no tener que ingresar todos los tipos de dato a la vez

```
 typedef struct Nodo{
     long rut;
     string digiv;
     string nom;
     string apellipa;
     string apellima;
     int dianaci;
     int mesnaci;
     int anonaci;
     string direc;
     int numm; 
     string comu;
     int sufra;
     int vocalm;
     int numca;
    struct Nodo *link;
}Nodo;
```

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más claro? Los `template` solo existen en C++. Y en C++ no necesitas escribir `struct` antes del nombre de la estructura por lo que el `typedef` es innecesario.

Comment: el struct es para crear el nodo, lo que me falta es implementar el template para utilizar la clase necesaria y acceder a sus datos y así que en el struct no tenga que poner todos los tipos de datos (long, int, string) o en dicho caso, saber si es posible implementarlo o no

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres un nodo plantilla sobre un tipo empieza por decir que es una plantilla:

```
template <typename dato_t>
```

Sigue con la definición del nodo:

```
struct Nodo
{
    Nodo *link{nullptr};
```

Y acaba con el uso de tu dato:

```
    dato_t dato;
};
```

Todo junto:

```
struct Dato
{
    long rut;
    string digiv;
    string nom;
    string apellipa;
    string apellima;
    int dianaci;
    int mesnaci;
    int anonaci;
    string direc;
    int numm; 
    string comu;
    int sufra;
    int vocalm;
    int numca;
};

template <typename dato_t>
struct Nodo
{
    Nodo *link{nullptr};
    dato_t dato;
};

// Uso:
Nodo<Dato> nd;
```

Comment: muchas gracias, al final termine cargando el archivo por medio de una clase y se me hizo un poco más fácil